# Gravitational force and potential in infite slab

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity, symmetry

Let's say that we have an infinite slab of height $2h$ and mass density $\rho$. Let's define $x,y$ as the axis parallel to the slab and $z$ as the perpendicular one, with $z=0$ at the middle of the slab. I want to calculate the gravitational potential and the force as function of $z$ inside the slab.

Due to the symmetry of the system, Gauss theorem works wonders. I get $\vec{g} = -4\pi G \rho z \hat{k}$, being $\hat{k}$ the unitary $z$ vector. Integrating I get $\Phi(z) = 2\pi G \rho z^2$.

However the provided solution is $\vec{g} = -8\pi G \rho z \hat{k}$ and $\Phi(z) = 4\pi G \rho z^2$, and I cannot guess where the factor of 2 comes from.

What did I miss in the derivation?

Edit: My derivation is:

Starting with Gauss
$\iint_{\partial{V}}\vec{g}\vec{dA} = -4 \pi G M$

Due to symmetry we have only force in $z$, so let $V$ be a cylinder of base $A$ and height $2h$ centered on $z=0$, then:

$g \cdot 2A = -4\pi G(\rho M 2 z A)$

$g = -4\pi G\rho z$

Integrating to get the potential, $\nabla \Phi = -\vec{g}$

$\Phi(z) = 2\pi G\rho z^2$

Comment: I posted a nice answer to this and then realized I had made a mistake and actually got the same answer as you. So either the provided answer is wrong, or you and I are both confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your answer is correct and the provided answer is wrong. Starting with [Gauss's law for gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity),  $-\nabla\cdot\vec g = 4\pi G\rho$, or equivalently Poisson's equation for gravity, $\nabla^2\phi = 4\pi G\rho$.

From the symmetry of the problem, $\phi$ has no $x$ or $y$ dependence:
$$\nabla^2\phi=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=4\pi G\rho$$
Integrate twice:
$$\phi = 2\pi G\rho z^2 + C_1 z + C_2$$
Since the problem is symmetric between $z$ and $-z$, $C_1$ must be zero, and we can make $C_2$ zero by choice of gauge. Then:
$$\vec g = -\nabla\phi = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\hat k = -4\pi G\rho z\hat k$$
in accord with your solution.

Comment: Thank you, for a moment there I thought that my derivation was wrong. But after the edit I see that using Poisson's equation renders the same answer. I also think that the solution may be wrong